# Create a unique "global" colormap to use across multiple stacked bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, colormap

I want to create a colormap that is not a simple array of colors, but rather like a dictionary, where I have each color assigned to a specific tag.

My data is in the form of data-frames where I have fractional numbers for each specific tag. Here below is a simplified example:

```
T1 = pd.DataFrame({'S1': [0.7, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0, 0.03, 0.033, 0.033, 0, 0]}, index=['B','C','D','F','G','H','I','M','N','P'])
T2 = pd.DataFrame({'S2': [0.6, 0.1, 0.1,  0.05, 0.05, 0.033, 0.033, 0.033, 0]}, index=['A','D','E','F','G','H','I','L','M'])
```

What I want is to plot my data as stacked bars.

This I can do: is rather straightforward and each stacked block (or category) is coloured differently. However, each category is given a colour automatically, assigned by the plot function to be consistent within a single plot (which is obviously what the majority of users need).

What I want is to be able to create a "permanent" colormap to maintain the colors across different plots consistent. Then I can plot each data-frame separately, but ensure that every category always appears the same color (i.e. 'G' is always red).

Since the list of categories can be 50-60 long once united, I need to assign them unique random colors.

M.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, this could help:

```
import matplotlib._color_data as mcd
import pandas as pd

index1 = ['B','C','D','F','G','H','I','M','N','P']
index2 = ['A','D','E','F','G','H','I','L','M']
T1 = pd.DataFrame({'S1': [0.7, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0, 0.03, 0.033, 0.033, 0, 0]}, index=index1)
T2 = pd.DataFrame({'S2': [0.6, 0.1, 0.1,  0.05, 0.05, 0.033, 0.033, 0.033, 0]}, index=index2)

indexes = set(index1).union(set(index2))
colores = list(mcd.XKCD_COLORS.values())[0:len(indexes)]
paleta = {i:c  for i, c in zip(indexes, colores)}

T1.T.plot.bar(color=T1.index.map(paleta), stacked=True)
T2.T.plot.bar(color=T2.index.map(paleta), stacked=True)
```

I create a dict with index as key and colors as values, then I map the index of each df using the dict.